# Using plain text as key and IV in PHP's mcrypt

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt, tripledes

I have an application that exchanges data between vendor's application in a TripleDES encryption using CBC method upon an agreed key and IV. My application is a VB.NET application while the vendor's application is a PHP web page. The strange thing is that I cannot seem to match the output of the vendor's application.

The key and initial vector are given to both of us in plaintext. The funny thing is, in the vendor's application, they don't hash or convert the key and IV to a 256 bit key and 128 bit IV. They just use the plaintext format in their code using **mcrypt** plugin in PHP.

```
$key = 'plaintextkey';
$iv = 'plaintextIV'
$enc = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv)
```

And it resulted in a funny text such as:

```
û!‰+«°z0"üÐÑn
```

My questions are:

1. should a plaintext be used as a parameter, how does PHP
   implement/convert it into a 256 bit character?
2. if CBC method is used, shouldn't it depend on the previously
   encrypted text?
3. is there a TripleDES result in my given format? Because as I
   searched through the internet and never have I seen a resulted
   encryption in such form.

Comment: Then I guess thay have taken a rather simplistic approach. Try pointing them to the [PHP Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) where it suggests the correct way to do things, all be it in an example rather than the description of the mcrypt functions

Comment: @RiggsFolly So, their use of key and IV was wrong? I see that in previous version of PHP they added \0 padding _Previously keys and IVs were padded with '\0' bytes to the next valid size._, so if they were using the latest PHP, it would've returned false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should a plaintext be used as a parameter, how does PHP implement/convert it into a 256 bit character?

Triple DES is and application of DES three times with three (different) DES keys. One DES key is 56 bit long and 64 bit with parity. So, a 3DES key is supposed to be composed of three *different* DES keys which should result in one 192 bit key.

Keys are supposed to have high entropy so that it would be necessary to brute-force a considerable amount of the key space. If the key is a password, then this is considerably easier, because passwords have a inherent format and a limited character set. That's why key need to be derived from passwords. This is usually done with PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt (with a randomly generated salt and a lot of iterations in the thousands or millions/high cost factor).

Now, mcrypt has made some questionable decisions. For example it happily accepted (in earlier PHP versions) invalid keys and IVs by padding them with 0x00 bytes to the next valid size or cropping them to the next valid size. That's why using "plaintextkey" is not a good idea. It will result in 0x00 bytes for some bytes of the second key and full 0x00 bytes for the third key.

**mcrypt is abandonware and should not be used anymore.** You can use the OpenSSL extension in PHP or one of the many good encryption libraries like libsodium or defuse/php-encryption.

> if CBC method is used, shouldn't it depend on the previously encrypted text?

You could use the last ciphertext block as the IV for the next encryption, but that only complicates the encryption code. You really should be using a random IV each time and simply prepend it to the ciphertext. It doesn't have to be secret, but rather unpredictable. You can store it alongside of the random salt from before. See also: [Why use an Initialization Vector (IV)?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/732/13022)

> is there a TripleDES result in my given format? Because as I searched through the internet and never have I seen a resulted encryption in such form.

Modern ciphers (with format-preserving encryption being a notable exception) produce ciphertexts that should be [indistinguishable from random "noise"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1646/13022). So, you may receive non-printable characters such as \x01 and many more as part of the ciphertext. You want to print ciphertext, then you need to encode into some printable format in example using Hex or Base 64.

Comment: Wow, this really helps a lot. So in short, to match the vendor's output, I gotta add some Zeros padding to my key and vector, right? I wanted to tell them that mcrypt is outdated but I don't it's my place to say so. :(

Comment: Yes, filling the key up to 24 byte with 0x00 bytes and cropping the IV at first 8 bytes should do fine. Keep in mind that mcrypt uses zero padding for the plaintext too. It will automatically pad the plaintext to the next multiple of the block size (8 byte for 3DES). Though, it doesn't add a full block of padding if the plaintext is already a multiple of the block size. This is probably a different behavior than ` System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.Zeros` which always adds at least one padding byte. You should try it out, because the way it works in PHP, it might still be compatible.

Comment: Dude, I finally did it. Thanks very much for your answers and I'll update my question with my solution as well. *Long distance fist bump*

Comment: No, don't add a solution to your question. You can post an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Artjom's answer for mentioning that you need to add several 0s until the key and IV reaches a length of 24 and 8 respectively. Here are the VB.NET codes in case someone needs it.

```
Dim byteKey As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("myplaintextkey")
Dim byteVector As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("myplaintextiv")

Dim base64Key As String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteKey)
Dim base64Vector As String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteVector)

Dim key As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Key)
Dim iv As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Vector)

Dim encryptor As SymmetricEncryptor = New SymmetricEncryptor() 'Note, this an internal library

Try
    encryptor.Provider = New System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider

    encryptor.Encoder = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    encryptor.Provider.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
    encryptor.Provider.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros

    'Add missing zeros to key and IV
    If key.Length < 24 Then
        Dim i As Integer = key.Length
        ReDim Preserve key(23)
        While i < 24
            key(i) = 0
            i += 1
        End While
    ElseIf key.Length > 24 Then
        ReDim Preserve key(23)
    End If

    If iv.Length < 8 Then
        Dim i As Integer = iv.Length
        ReDim Preserve iv(8)
        While i < 8
            iv(i) = 0
            i += 1
        End While
    ElseIf iv.Length > 8 Then
        ReDim Preserve iv(8)
    End If
    encryptor.IV = iv
    encryptor.Key = key

    Dim output As String = encryptor.Encrypt(output)

    Console.Write(output)
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.Write(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I hope it helps someone and once again, thank you Artjom!